# Reading items with multiple items in same line

Tags: python, file-io, rows

I'm trying to get my program to read an infile and plot it out on a graph. It worked when the infile contained only one item per line, but in this new file, there are multiple items in the same line:

> Line 1:  -4.6653184e-01  -3.9003953e-01  -1.3689525e+00  -2.9784036e-01  -1.2366933e+00  -1.4433164e+00  -1.7245383e+00  -2.2787106e+00  -9.8088629e-01  -1.9053069e+00  -1.7806724e+00  -3.1259933e+00  -2.1796645e+00  -1.8323782e+00  -1.9089487e+00  -3.6322765e+00
>
> Line 2:   -8.9710621e-01  -6.2431759e-01  -1.4762999e+00  -2.2668609e-01  -1.6593426e+00  -1.5644687e+00  -2.4312715e+00  -2.8894224e+00  -1.7810424e+00  -2.2357098e+00  -2.8545336e+00  -3.7422563e+00  -3.0884226e+00  -2.9146711e+00  -3.3407812e+00  -5.2601065e+00

I was able to do it before with

> lines = infile.readlines()

while in a for loop, but now I'm not sure where to go from here. I'm fairly new to python and I would appreciate help.

Also, note that there are about 35,000 lines and I cannot just go into the text file and "enter" after every entry. Thank you!

Comment: You can use sed to achieve "enter" after every line: sed s/ /\n/g <filename>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do. From the lines you've pasted, if you want to pick all the values as a **single dataset** you could substitute what you have with:

```
lines = []
[lines.extend(_.split()) for _ in fd.readlines()]
print lines
```

This will give you one value per position of the array:

```
['-4.6653184e-01', '-3.9003953e-01', '-1.3689525e+00', '-2.9784036e-01', '-1.2366933e+00', '-1.4433164e+00', '-1.7245383e+00', '-2.2787106e+00', '-9.8088629e-01', '-1.9053069e+00', '-1.7806724e+00', '-3.1259933e+00', '-2.1796645e+00', '-1.8323782e+00', '-1.9089487e+00', '-3.6322765e+00', '-8.9710621e-01', '-6.2431759e-01', '-1.4762999e+00', '-2.2668609e-01', '-1.6593426e+00', '-1.5644687e+00', '-2.4312715e+00', '-2.8894224e+00', '-1.7810424e+00', '-2.2357098e+00', '-2.8545336e+00', '-3.7422563e+00', '-3.0884226e+00', '-2.9146711e+00', '-3.3407812e+00', '-5.2601065e+00']
```

If you want to create a matrix of data in which each column is a **separate dataset**, then you substitute your `readlines` with:

```
lines = [_.split() for _ in fd.readlines()
```

which will generate (in your example) a matrix of two rows and N columns such as:

```
[['-4.6653184e-01', '-3.9003953e-01', '-1.3689525e+00', '-2.9784036e-01', '-1.2366933e+00', '-1.4433164e+00', '-1.7245383e+00', '-2.2787106e+00', '-9.8088629e-01', '-1.9053069e+00', '-1.7806724e+00', '-3.1259933e+00', '-2.1796645e+00', '-1.8323782e+00', '-1.9089487e+00', '-3.6322765e+00'],
 ['-8.9710621e-01', '-6.2431759e-01', '-1.4762999e+00', '-2.2668609e-01', '-1.6593426e+00', '-1.5644687e+00', '-2.4312715e+00', '-2.8894224e+00', '-1.7810424e+00', '-2.2357098e+00', '-2.8545336e+00', '-3.7422563e+00', '-3.0884226e+00', '-2.9146711e+00', '-3.3407812e+00', '-5.2601065e+00']]
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because `.readlines()` is doing just that; it will take all of the  values that it finds on a single line and append it to your list as a single item. Instead, in each of your lines, you need an additional step that separates out each number in the line based on the delimiter. For this we can use `.split()` and specify the delimiter as an empty string (which is the same as a single space).

```
output_to_plot = []

with open('multi_items.txt', 'r') as infile:
    for line in infile:
        output_to_plot.extend([float(item) for item in line.split(' ')])

print(output_to_plot)
```

Answer (score 0):

If all the values are separated by whitespace, you can simply use

```
for line in lines:
    items = line.split()
```

If they are separated by something else, use `line.split(separator)`. This will split the string at every occurence of `separator` (if no separator is supplied, it will split after consecutive whitespace) and return a list of items which you can then further process.